# Download location of pdf files saved in the of Academia app

Tags: applications, downloading

Using [Academia free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.academia.academia) and downloading papers: where are these papers downloaded on the system? I don't see a specific setting for that in the app, at least not in the free version.

I want to open the downloaded pdf in a pdf viewer, not in the app (although I know I can download the same pdf in the browser etc).

For now, what I do is open the PDF in the app and use the "share  file" option.

[image]

Thus, I can get the pdf file with the app to which it is shared (whatsapp, gmail, sms etc).

But I would prefer to know the download path  - if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android usage Linux based kernel and security, so every app runs in its own sandbox. Although storing app specific files depends on the developer most of them store in app specific folders which again can either be accessible by user or not. If you can't find any app specific folder created on your sdCard(external storage) look for `/Android/data/yourAppSpecificPackageFolder` [in your case `/Android/data/com.academia.academia`] in internal storage, you can look for folders within this. It can be stored as it is(`.pdf`) or some other format which default applications might not understand(so you can't open it).
If you don't find here then it might be in  `/data/data/yourAppSpecificPackageFolder` for which you need to have rooted device.

Comment: The packageName of the app is known, hence you can at least provide the complete path for that app, instead of posting a generic path. Additionally on Linux `/Android` means the folder Android in the root folder, hence I assume you mean `/sdcard/Android...`.

Comment: The only item called "academia" is indeed /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.academia.academia, but no pdfs there. My only clue that the pdfs are really on the device (by contrast to just being virtually put in a library) is the fact that by sharing the file to gmail, Whatsapp, etc I can get the pdf. By the way, the device is NOT rooted.

Comment: @cipricus it will be mostly on device(as you can share it through whtsApp etc this will be better option for developer to do). if you can't find even on internal storage folder then it must be in /data/data which will require root access.